# custom actionbar title in android

Tags: java, android

hey guys i want help in setting my current activity title in my custom actionbar.

my on create function:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        //i guess the line below is wrong
        actionBar.setTitle(this.getTitle());

        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }
```

**actionbar_custom_view_home.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageIcon"
        android:onClick="Click"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So what are you asking here? What isn't working?

Comment: @Neil i am not getting the title in my custom actionbar

Comment: I did mistake. Try themes. Creator themes: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ Other example:
http://shreymalhotra.me/blog/tutorial/android-create-custom-themes-for-your-apps/

Comment: You can use Sherlock Action Bar.. I hope this link will be helpful. try this http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: Isn't it the problem: actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false) ?